# JQuery .each() returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I am having two tables. The first one is only for the headers, because I didn´t found a solution to make the thead non scrollable. the Second one contains the content, but is empty when the side gets loaded. First the Code for both tables.

```
            <table width="100%">
                <caption class="splitselection">
                    <b>Downloads</b>
                </caption>
                <thead align="left">
                    <tr> 
                        <th scope="col" width="36%"   align="left"          >Dateiname           </th>
                        <th scope="col" width="32%"   align="left"          >Fortschritt         </th>
                        <th scope="col" id="status" width="22%"align="left" >Status              </th>
                        <th scope="col" width="10%" align="left"            >Ordner &ouml;ffnen  </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <div style="overflow:auto; height:115px;  width:100%" class="downloadFrame">
                <table width="100%" id="download_table" align="center">
                    <tbody align="left">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

so for now I want to catch every `<tr>` element in the table with the content with this code:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#download_table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
        alert($(this).find('td')[0].html);
    });
},5000);
```

I am creating a interval which checks a specific tablecell.

In my Alert I want to retrieve this tablecell, but my Alert in here return me "undefined".
If I am just writing `alert($(this).find('td')[0]);` it return me HTML `htmlObjectTableCell`.

Without adding any tablerow, my interval does nothing. If i add a row, I am getting an alert. So for me there must be something wrong when I want to get the tablecell html

Yet I tried to use .html .val and .text, but I am getting the same result as before.

Comment: You have no `<TD>` in your table ..

Comment: i Know, but i am adding them while the user is one the side. I am having the same amount of <td> then the table on top of the "download_table"

Comment: Show us the actual code rendered on the page then, after you have added the data to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
```

or

```
$(this).find('td:first-child').html();
```

By the way, `$("foo").html` returns a reference to the `html` function rather than invoking it. Make sure you use `function_name()` instead of `function_name` when you want to actually execute a function named `function_name`.

### Explanation

In jQuery, `$('selector')[0]`, does not return a jQuery-wrapped object but a PODO (Plain Old Dom Object anyone?). That means you can not call jQuery functions on the returned object. However `$('selector').eq(0)` returns a jQuery-wrapped object so you can invoke jQuery functions on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through each tr that is a direct child to the tbody-element that is the direct child of #download_table. What your markup is showing is that the tbody-element doesn't have any children at all.

Comment: That would result in no alerts, not an alert of `undefined`; I'm assuming he's dynamically adding the `<tr>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML of the contents of a DOM element is stored in the `innerHTML` property, not a property called `html`, so you need to change that line to this:

```
alert($(this).find('td')[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no `<td>` in table

Comment: thanks above all , i am new to stack over flow  . Will try to be more specific next time